# exclude a variable combination from trees in randomForest R

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm fitting random forest models in R using the `randomForest` package. I would like to fit two models, one with covariates `a`, `b` and many other covariates (`x1 to xn`), and a second with the covariates `a`, `b`, and `a * 1/b` (the interaction of `a` and `b`) plus the additional covariates `x1 to xn`. However, in the first fit, if I have `a` and `b` both in a random forest model, and if both `a` and `b` end up in the same tree, the model will essentially considering the interaction between `a` and `b`.

Is it possible to tell the random forest model to never include covariates `a` and `b` in the same tree? If so, how might I implement this in the `randomForest` package in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to modify the source code of the package, you cannot do this. But, if I understand your question correctly, you can more or less do this by creating two random forest models. One that includes a, but not b, and the other to include b, but not a. Then just take the average prediction from the two models. Computationally this is probably the same as what you are trying to do.